# How to identify deep cloning and swallow cloning

Tags: java, collections

## How to identify in the following code that it is performing deep cloning and shallow cloning.

```
import java.util.HashMap;
import java.util.Iterator;

public final class FinalClassExample {
private final int id;

    private final String name;

    private final HashMap<String,String> testMap;

    public int getId() {
        return id;
    }


    public String getName() {
        return name;
    }

    /**
     * Accessor function for mutable objects
     */
    public HashMap<String, String> getTestMap() {
        //return testMap;
        return (HashMap<String, String>) testMap.clone();
    }

    /**
     * Constructor performing Deep Copy
     * @param i
     * @param n
     * @param hm
     */

    public FinalClassExample(int i, String n, HashMap<String,String> hm){
        System.out.println("Performing Deep Copy for Object initialization");
        this.id=i;
        this.name=n;
        HashMap<String,String> tempMap=new HashMap<String,String>();
        String key;
        Iterator<String> it = hm.keySet().iterator();
        while(it.hasNext()){
            key=it.next();
            tempMap.put(key, hm.get(key));
        }
        this.testMap=tempMap;
    }


    /**
     * Constructor performing Shallow Copy
     * @param i
     * @param n
     * @param hm
     */
    /**
    public FinalClassExample(int i, String n, HashMap<String,String> hm){
        System.out.println("Performing Shallow Copy for Object initialization");
        this.id=i;
        this.name=n;
        this.testMap=hm;
    }
    */

    /**
     * To test the consequences of Shallow Copy and how to avoid it with Deep Copy for creating immutable classes
     * @param args
     */
    public static void main(String[] args) {
        HashMap<String, String> h1 = new HashMap<String,String>();
        h1.put("1", "first");
        h1.put("2", "second");

        String s = "original";

        int i=10;

        FinalClassExample ce = new FinalClassExample(i,s,h1);

        //Lets see whether its copy by field or reference
        System.out.println(s==ce.getName());
        System.out.println(h1 == ce.getTestMap());
        //print the ce values
        System.out.println("ce id:"+ce.getId());
        System.out.println("ce name:"+ce.getName());
        System.out.println("ce testMap:"+ce.getTestMap());
        //change the local variable values
        i=20;
        s="modified";
        h1.put("3", "third");
        //print the values again
        System.out.println("ce id after local variable change:"+ce.getId());
        System.out.println("ce name after local variable change:"+ce.getName());
        System.out.println("ce testMap after local variable change:"+ce.getTestMap());

        HashMap<String, String> hmTest = ce.getTestMap();
        hmTest.put("4", "new");

        System.out.println("ce testMap after changing variable from accessor methods:"+ce.getTestMap());

    }

}
```

Comment: Just print the object before & after clone?

Comment: There is no cloning going on. There is no deep copying going on. The constructor does copy the map the long way around (`this.testMap = new HashMap<>(hm);` would have done it in a single line). Can't really call it deep or shallow, since keys and values are immutable Strings. Now, if you created a copy-constructor that didn't copy the map, that would be a shallow copy, and if it did copy the map, that would be a deep copy. But your code is doing none of that, so your terms don't really apply. Your commented out shallow constructor isn't copying *any* objects, so it's not a shallow *copy*.

Comment: @MuhammadFaizanUddin How does that show whether the map was copied or the reference to the map was shared? Printing the map would show exactly the same in both cases.

Comment: Every object has it's own object_id, through that you can keep a track!